# Specifing the height of an element relative to two other elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am trying to achieve a website layout that works like this: http://tzd-themes.com/gebo_admin/index.php?uid=1&page=dashboard.

And I would like to add a footer.

The way the footer would work is the following: when you scroll to the end of the page, there is a footer that take all the width of the page, and pushing the sidebar up if it needs to, **causing the sidebar to shrink**. So essentially what I am tryng to do is specify the height of the sidebar as being the distance bewteen the bottom of the header and the top of the footer, with `overflow: auto;`.

You can fiddle here (with more explanations):
http://jsfiddle.net/xK4B5/

Comment: Why would you want the footer to overlap the sidebar?  If the sidebar is fixed in height, wouldn't overlapping content be a concern?  I feel like what you're trying to achieve is slightly inelegant.

Comment: I don't want the sidebar to be fixed in height. I want the sidebar to take all the space available when the footer is not visible, but when the footer comes up, it pushes the sidebar up (as I said in the question: at any moment, the height of the sidebar is the distance bewteen the bottom of the header and the top of the footer)

Comment: You most likely can't achieve that with pure CSS, since you're changing the way the fixed sidebar would behave.  If you feel the complication warrants the results, then proceed.  I personally would avoid such a implementation unless the benefits increased the usability for the user significantly.

Comment: @Axel What would you suggest as a simple solution instead ? I have tought of simply adding the footer below the main content with a `<hr/>`in between. But that way the footer is hard to distinguish from the content.

Comment: I would keep the footer inside of the content area.  It really depends on what you're trying to present in the footer area.

Answer (score 0):

Have a header, main section, and footer, the main section will contains the content and the side bar.  Set the sidebars height to 100% (if that doesn't work for whatever reason, position it absolute - left:0,top:0,bottom:0,right:auto)  this will cause it to take up however much space your main content is height wise.  So if your content is short (causing the footer to come up) the sidebar will also shorten.

```
#sidebar {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     right:auto;
     width: 200px;
}

#content {
     margin-left: 200px;
     width: 700px;
}
```

Should get you close to your desired effect.

Comment: Also note, the main section's position will need to be position:relative so that the sidebar's absolute position will be relative to the main content.